# Save a file from requests using django filesystem

Tags: django

I'm currently trying to save a file via requests, it's rather large, so I'm instead streaming it.

I'm unsure how to specifically do this, as I keep getting different errors.  This is what I have so far.

```
def download_file(url, matte_upload_path, matte_servers, job_name, count):
    local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    url = "%s/static/downloads/%s_matte/%s/%s" % (matte_servers[0], job_name, count, local_filename)
    with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
        r.raise_for_status()
        fs = FileSystemStorage(location=matte_upload_path)
        print(matte_upload_path, 'matte path upload')
        with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=8192):
                f.write(chunk)
            fs.save(local_filename, f)

    return local_filename
```

but it returns

```
io.UnsupportedOperation: read
```

I'm basically trying to have requests save it to the specific location via django, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this, by using a tempfile to save the python requests, then saving it via the `FileSystemStorage`

```
    local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    url = "%s/static/downloads/%s_matte/%s/%s" % (matte_servers[0], job_name, count, local_filename)
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    fs = FileSystemStorage(location=matte_upload_path)
    lf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()

    # Read the streamed image in sections
    for block in response.iter_content(1024 * 8):

        # If no more file then stop
        if not block:
            break

        # Write image block to temporary file
        lf.write(block)
    fs.save(local_filename, lf)
```